# Custom post type - displaying sets of data if selected on Worpdress back end

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type

I am trying to extend a custom wordpress plugin that displays sets of data stored on the Wordpress database when an option is setup on the backend via a custom metabox on a custom post type.
At the moment it is displaying two custom sets of data but I need to add a third one. I think my php skills are obviously not up to scratch for this one as I keep getting the error below:

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file  on line 103

```
<?php if ($contestedby2013 == true || $contested2013 == true) { ?>
        <div class="row" id="data-row-ie">
        <div class="span12">
            <ul id="result-graph-tabs" class="nav nav-tabs" style="margin-top:20px;margin-bottom:0;">   
                <li><a href="#olderresults" data-toggle="tab">Older election data</a></li>
                <?php if($contested2005 == true) {echo '<li><a href="#results2005full" data-toggle="tab">2005 full election results</a></li>';}?>
                <?php if($contestedby2008 == true) {echo '<li><a href="#results2008by" data-toggle="tab">2008 by-election results</a></li>';}?>
                <?php if($contested2009 == true) {echo '<li><a href="#results2009full" data-toggle="tab">2009 full election results</a></li>';}?>
                <?php if($contestedby2009 == true) {echo '<li><a href="#results2009by" data-toggle="tab">2009 by-election results</a></li>';}?>
                <?php if($contested2010 == true) {echo '<li><a href="#results2010by" data-toggle="tab">2010 by-election results</a></li>';}?>
                <?php if($contested2013 == true) {echo '<li><a href="#results2013full" data-toggle="tab">2013 full election results</a></li>';}?>
                <?php if($contestedby2013 == true) {echo '<li><a href="#results2013by" data-toggle="tab">2013 by-election results</a></li>';}?>
            </ul>
            <div id="result-graph-tabs-content" class="tab-content">
                <div class="tab-pane" id="olderresults">
                <div class="row">
                <div class="span12">
                <h3>Older election result data for <?php echo $electoral_area_title; ?> area</h3><p>Before the 2005 election, county level electoral boundaries in Warwickshire were slightly different. Because of this difference, data isn't displayed alongside the 2005, 2009 and 2013 results - but it is still available to view and download through the <a href="//opendata.warwickshire.gov.uk/tags/elections">opendata.warwickshire.gov.uk</a> website.</p>
                </div>
                </div>
                </div>
                <?php include('tab-logic-2005-full.php');?>
                <?php include('tab-logic-2008-by.php');?>
                <?php include('tab-logic-2009-full.php');?>
                <?php include('tab-logic-2009-by.php');?>
                <?php include('tab-logic-2010-by.php');?>
                <?php include('tab-logic-2013-full.php');?>
                <?php include('tab-logic-2013-by.php');?>
            </div> 
        </div>
        </div>
<!-- Displays extra data set if selected -->
<?php if ($contestedby2014 == true || $contested2013 == true) { ?>

        <div class="row" id="data-row-ie">
        <div class="span12">
            <ul id="result-graph-tabs" class="nav nav-tabs" style="margin-top:20px;margin-bottom:0;">   
                <li><a href="#olderresults" data-toggle="tab">Older election data</a></li>
                <?php if($contested2005 == true) {echo '<li><a href="#results2005full" data-toggle="tab">2005 full election results</a></li>';}?>
                <?php if($contestedby2008 == true) {echo '<li><a href="#results2008by" data-toggle="tab">2008 by-election results</a></li>';}?>
                <?php if($contested2009 == true) {echo '<li><a href="#results2009full" data-toggle="tab">2009 full election results</a></li>';}?>
                <?php if($contestedby2009 == true) {echo '<li><a href="#results2009by" data-toggle="tab">2009 by-election results</a></li>';}?>
                <?php if($contested2010 == true) {echo '<li><a href="#results2010by" data-toggle="tab">2010 by-election results</a></li>';}?>
                <?php if($contested2013 == true) {echo '<li><a href="#results2013full" data-toggle="tab">2013 full election results</a></li>';}?>
                <?php if($contestedby2014 == true) {echo '<li><a href="#results2014by" data-toggle="tab">2013 by-election results</a></li>';}?>
            </ul>
            <div id="result-graph-tabs-content" class="tab-content">
                <div class="tab-pane" id="olderresults">
                <div class="row">
                <div class="span12">
                <h3>Older election result data for <?php echo $electoral_area_title; ?> area</h3><p>Before the 2005 election, county level electoral boundaries in Warwickshire were slightly different. Because of this difference, data isn't displayed alongside the 2005, 2009 and 2013 results - but it is still available to view and download through the <a href="//opendata.warwickshire.gov.uk/tags/elections">opendata.warwickshire.gov.uk</a> website.</p>
                </div>
                </div>
                </div>
                <?php include('tab-logic-2005-full.php');?>
                <?php include('tab-logic-2008-by.php');?>
                <?php include('tab-logic-2009-full.php');?>
                <?php include('tab-logic-2009-by.php');?>
                <?php include('tab-logic-2010-by.php');?>
                <?php include('tab-logic-2013-full.php');?>
                <?php include('tab-logic-2014-by.php');?>
            </div> 
        </div>
        </div>
<?php } ?>
<!--End of additional data set  -->
<?php } else { ?>
                <div class="row" id="data-row-ie">
                <div class="span12">
                <ul id="result-graph-tabs" class="nav nav-tabs" style="margin-top:20px;margin-bottom:0;">   
                <li><a href="#olderresults" data-toggle="tab">Older election data</a></li>
                <?php if($contested2005 == true) {echo '<li><a href="#results2005full" data-toggle="tab">2005 full election results</a></li>';}?>
                <?php if($contestedby2008 == true) {echo '<li><a href="#results2008by" data-toggle="tab">2008 by-election results</a></li>';}?>
                <?php if($contested2009 == true) {echo '<li><a href="#results2009full" data-toggle="tab">2009 full election results</a></li>';}?>
                <?php if($contestedby2009 == true) {echo '<li><a href="#results2009by" data-toggle="tab">2009 by-election results</a></li>';}?>
                <?php if($contested2010 == true) {echo '<li><a href="#results2010by" data-toggle="tab">2010 by-election results</a></li>';}?>
                <?php if($contested2013 == true) {echo '<li><a href="#results2013full" data-toggle="tab">2013 full election results</a></li>';}?>
            </ul>
            <div id="result-graph-tabs-content" class="tab-content">
                <div class="tab-pane" id="olderresults">
                <div class="row">
                <div class="span12">
                <h3>Older election result data for <?php echo $electoral_area_title; ?> area</h3><p>Before the 2005 election, county level electoral boundaries in Warwickshire were slightly different. Because of this difference, data isn't displayed alongside the 2005, 2009 and 2013 results - but it is still available to view and download through the <a href="//opendata.warwickshire.gov.uk/tags/elections">opendata.warwickshire.gov.uk</a> website.</p>
                </div>
                </div>
                </div>
                <?php include('tab-logic-2005-full.php');?>
                <?php include('tab-logic-2008-by.php');?>
                <?php include('tab-logic-2009-full.php');?>
                <?php include('tab-logic-2009-by.php');?>
                <?php include('tab-logic-2010-by.php');?>
                <?php include('tab-logic-2013-full.php');?> <!-- added 2013 by elections result tab - NM 3.12.2013  -->
            </div> 
        </div>
        </div>
<? php } ?>
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: please paste the full code... or you will try ..please remove <?php } ?> before <!--End of additional data set  --> comment ....

Comment: Thanks.. should have spotted that.  Quite a complex plugin so can't paste full code.